# Subspace spanned by the vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulty understanding this question:

Graph the subspace spanned by the vectors $i = (3,-2,-1)^T$, $j = (-2,0,-1)^T$.

You don't have to graph it, but the answer for this problem is $z = (-3/5)x - (6/5)y$. I don't understand how to come up with that answer. I tried setting $i=-j$ but to no avail. Also, sorry for writing $i,j$ with $^T$, I do not know how to format it to make it look like a column vector.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right answer? The points $(3,-2,-1)$ and $(-2,0,-1)$ don't seem to be on that plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something is not quite right here.

Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can find the normal to the plane spanned by $i, j$ by $i \times j = (2,5,-4)^T$, hence the equation of the plane is $\langle (x,y,z)^T, i \times j \rangle = 2x+5y-4z =0$, which gives $z = \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{5}{4} y$.

Here is another approach that does not use the cross product:

Suppose $(x,y,z) = a i + b j = (3a-2b, -2a, -(a+b))$. Then, from $y$ we have $a = -\frac{y}{2}$, and from $x$ we have $b = -\frac{3}{4} y -\frac{1}{2} x$. Then $z = -(a+b) = \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{5}{4} y$.

Comment: How did you get z=1/2x + 5/4y and (2,5,-4)^T ? We haven't been taught the cross product yet.

Comment: I added another approach.

Comment: I understand now because of your help, thank you very much copper!!

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to be of help.

Comment: How do I come to know that a and b must be eliminated from the equation.

Comment: @Vinod You want to find an $(x,y,z)$ description of the subspace. A general element is $ai+bj$. To find $(x,y,z)$ you equate the two. The relationship between $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ is bijective, so we can determine $z$ in terms of $x,y$.